# Printf function %p behave differently when it is given an array compared to a pointer

Tags: c, pointers, memory

In the first printf the output is the address of arr and I was expecting this. However in the second one it prints the same address. Isn't it supposed to print the "value" pointed to by arr ( which is the address 0 ) ?

```
 char * arr[2];
 char ** p;


 int main(){
 
  p = arr;

  printf("%p\n",&arr);
  printf("%p\n",arr);

  printf("%p\n",&p);
  printf("%p\n",p);

  /* OUTPUT 
  0x10aa71010
  0x10aa71010
  0x10aa71020
  0x10aa71010
  */

 }
```

Comment: When you use an array in an expression, what you get is a pointer to the array's first element.  This is sort of the first rule of arrays and pointers in C, also known as "array/pointer decay".

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by, or why you expected to get, "the address 0".  Since `&array` is a pointer to the array, and `array` by itself (per the "array decay" rule) is a pointer to the array's first element, it's expected for `array` and `&array` to have the same value.

Comment: "However in the second one it prints the same address." --> note the address of an array and the address of the first element of an array are _equivalent_, not necessarily the same pointer representation.

Comment: #Steve Summit You say that "array by itself is a pointer to the array's first element." Technically this is not true because as the definition says "a pointer is a variable that contains as its value the address of another variable". If we inspect the RAM, the "value" of array is not the address of its first element but it is whatever char pointer is to be found there. It would be more appropriate to say that "array is treated as a pointer to the first element of the array"

Answer (score 3):

The variable `p` is a pointer. It points to the first element of `arr`. Applying the **pointer-to** operator `&` (also known as the *address-of* operator) to `p` will create a pointer to the variable `p`.

Drawing it, it would be something like

```
+----+      +---+      +--------+
| &p | ---> | p | ---> | arr[0] |
+----+      +---+      +--------+
```

With arrays it's really the same, applying the pointer-to operator to an array gives you a pointer to the array. *But* the location of the array is the same as the location of the first element of the array.

Drawing it would be something like this:

```
+--------+--------+
| arr[0] | arr[1] |
+--------+--------+
^
|
&arr[0] (pointer to the first element, what plain arr decays to)
|
&arr    (pointer to the array itself)
```

From these "drawings" it should hopefully be easier to understand why `p` and `&p` would be different, as well as why `arr` and `&arr` would be the same.

Very important note: While `&arr` and `&arr[0]` point to the same location, the two pointers have *different type* and are therefore semantically different. Doing pointer arithmetic with the two pointers will not give the same result.

For your example, the type of `&arr` will be `char *(*)[2]`, while the type of `&arr[0]` will be `char **`.

---

On a technical and kind of nitpicking note, the `printf` format `%p` is really for printing `void *` pointers. And the pointers you pass to `printf` will have different types.

Mismatching format specifier and argument type leads to *undefined behavior*. So to be fully correct you need to cast all pointers to `void *`.

Answer (score 0):

After this assignment

```
p = arr;
```

the pointer `p` points to the first element of the array `arr`. Note that arrays used in expressions with rare exceptions are implicitly converted to pointers to their first elements.

Thus the address of the first element of the array `arr` is equal to the address of the array itself.

So this call of `printf`

```
printf("%p\n",p);
```

outputs the address of the first element of the array stored on the pointer `p` after its assignment.

On the other hand the array `arr` and the pointer `p` occupy different extents of memory.

```
char * arr[2];
char ** p;
```

And this call of `printf`

```
printf("%p\n",&p);
```

outputs the address of the pointer `p` itself.